# Cannot deploy BNA to Fabric: simulateProposal() results in chaincode response status 500?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to follow the [developer guide](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html), but deploying my business network definition (`composer network deploy -a my-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i admin -s adminpw`) fails with this error:

> Error: error trying deploy. Error: error trying install chaincode.

The logs on the Fabric side say this:

> simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode response status 500 for txid: c6b37624bc03f69251044df7...

The full log looks like this:

```
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:21.359 UTC [eventhub_producer] validateEventMessage -> DEBU 337 ValidateEventMessage starts for signed event 0xc421628ed0
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:21.360 UTC [eventhub_producer] registerHandler -> DEBU 338 registering event type: BLOCK
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.240 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 339 Entry
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.240 UTC [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> DEBU 33a ValidateProposalMessage starts for signed proposal 0xc42165a720
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.241 UTC [protoutils] validateChannelHeader -> DEBU 33b validateChannelHeader info: header type 3
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.241 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 33c checkSignatureFromCreator starts
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.241 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 33d checkSignatureFromCreator info: creator is &{Org1MSP fa44b0d6f3110751e9a7e80eabee209a1000969a585f0af65838df308e6b4fe1}
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.242 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 33e checkSignatureFromCreator info: creator is valid
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.256 UTC [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 33f checkSignatureFromCreator exists successfully
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.256 UTC [protoutils] validateChaincodeProposalMessage -> DEBU 340 validateChaincodeProposalMessage starts for proposal 0xc4216000f0, header 0xc42165a7b0
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.256 UTC [protoutils] validateChaincodeProposalMessage -> DEBU 341 validateChaincodeProposalMessage info: header extension references chaincode name:"lscc"
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.256 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 342 processing txid: c6b37624bc03f69251044df77c1f6d3d385a60c6d54eda5bf64e5ed6b62219ca
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.256 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> DEBU 343 Entry - txid: c6b37624bc03f69251044df77c1f6d3d385a60c6d54eda5bf64e5ed6b62219ca channel id:
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.350 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> DEBU 344 Entry - txid: c6b37624bc03f69251044df77c1f6d3d385a60c6d54eda5bf64e5ed6b62219ca channel id:  version: 1.0.0-rc1
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.351 UTC [ccprovider] NewCCContext -> DEBU 345 NewCCCC (chain=,chaincode=lscc,version=1.0.0-rc1,txid=c6b37624bc03f69251044df77c1f6d3d385a60c6d54eda5bf64e5ed6b62219ca,syscc=true,pro

posal=0xc4216000f0,canname=lscc:1.0.0-rc1
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.351 UTC [chaincode] Launch -> DEBU 346 chaincode is running(no need to launch) : lscc:1.0.0-rc1
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.357 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 347 Entry
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.358 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 348 chaincode canonical name: lscc:1.0.0-rc1
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.358 UTC [chaincode] sendExecuteMessage -> DEBU 349 [c6b37624]Inside sendExecuteMessage. Message TRANSACTION
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.358 UTC [chaincode] setChaincodeProposal -> DEBU 34a Setting chaincode proposal context...
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.358 UTC [chaincode] setChaincodeProposal -> DEBU 34b Proposal different from nil. Creating chaincode proposal context...
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.358 UTC [chaincode] sendExecuteMessage -> DEBU 34c [c6b37624]sendExecuteMsg trigger event TRANSACTION
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.359 UTC [chaincode] processStream -> DEBU 34d [c6b37624]Move state message TRANSACTION
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.359 UTC [chaincode] HandleMessage -> DEBU 34e [c6b37624]Fabric side Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: TRANSACTION in state ready
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.359 UTC [chaincode] filterError -> DEBU 34f Ignoring NoTransitionError: no transition
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.359 UTC [chaincode] processStream -> DEBU 350 [c6b37624]sending state message TRANSACTION
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.359 UTC [shim] func1 -> DEBU 351 [c6b37624]Received message TRANSACTION from shim
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.359 UTC [shim] handleMessage -> DEBU 352 [c6b37624]Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: TRANSACTION(state:ready)
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.359 UTC [shim] beforeTransaction -> DEBU 353 [c6b37624]Received TRANSACTION, invoking transaction on chaincode(Src:ready, Dst:ready)
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.382 UTC [shim] func1 -> DEBU 354 [c6b37624]Transaction completed. Sending COMPLETED
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.382 UTC [shim] func1 -> DEBU 355 [c6b37624]Move state message COMPLETED
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.382 UTC [shim] handleMessage -> DEBU 356 [c6b37624]Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED(state:ready)
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.383 UTC [shim] func1 -> DEBU 357 [c6b37624]send state message COMPLETED
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.383 UTC [chaincode] processStream -> DEBU 358 [c6b37624]Received message COMPLETED from shim
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.383 UTC [chaincode] HandleMessage -> DEBU 359 [c6b37624]Fabric side Handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED in state ready
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.383 UTC [chaincode] HandleMessage -> DEBU 35a [c6b37624bc03f69251044df77c1f6d3d385a60c6d54eda5bf64e5ed6b62219ca]HandleMessage- COMPLETED. Notify
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.383 UTC [chaincode] notify -> DEBU 35b notifying Txid:c6b37624bc03f69251044df77c1f6d3d385a60c6d54eda5bf64e5ed6b62219ca
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.383 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 35c Exit
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.384 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> DEBU 35d Exit
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.384 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> DEBU 35e Exit
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.384 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> ERRO 35f simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode response status 500 for txid: c6b37624bc03f69251044df77c1f6d3d385a60c6d54eda5bf64e5ed6b6221

9ca
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:29.404 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 360 Exit
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:30.157 UTC [eventhub_producer] validateEventMessage -> DEBU 361 ValidateEventMessage starts for signed event 0xc421629440
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:30.158 UTC [eventhub_producer] deRegisterHandler -> DEBU 362 deregistering event type: BLOCK
peer0.org1.example.com    | 2017-07-12 16:30:30.170 UTC [eventhub_producer] Chat -> ERRO 363 error during Chat, stopping handler: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode response status 500 for txid: c6b37624bc03f69251044df7
```

And I'm kinda stumped! What's going on, what does this error even mean? Looking around, I sort of get the impression this error means the chaincode is not valid?

Well, um, any advice?

Fabric is v1.0.0-rc1. Composer is v0.9.1. OS is a Debian/Jessie running in a Vagrant box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is the identity you are using to try to install chaincode onto a peer is not authorised to do so. Unfortunately the logs don't indicate this and the error returned to hyperledger-composer is empty for RC1 fabric.
If you are using the composer development server then it creates an identity for you called PeerAdmin which you should use to deploy business networks. If you are using your own fabric then you need to look into how to import crypto material for a peer administrator into composer using the `composer identity import` command documented here
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/composer.identity.import.html

Comment: @david_k the link is dead